# Can someone tell me what this document is saying?

Tags: property, real-property, liens

Context: I purchased some land and paid cash for it in full and owned it without any kind of lien. We then proceeded to begin the process of building a house. Secured a builder and a construction loan. As part of construction loan, we used the property as security for the loan. Due to the economic situation and rocket-ship-like rising mortgage rates, we backed out of the project and paid off the loan. We received this today from our bank. I know little law jargon, but it sounds like we are giving the bank our property. That doesn't make sense to me though. Can someone kindly explain this document to me?

[image]

Comment: Seems straightforward to me but if in doubt, consult a local attorney who practices real estate law.

Comment: @jwh20 To be fair, it looks like it was written by a lawyer who thinks they are still living in the middle ages. Modern legal practice (at least in my jurisdiction) discourages the use of archaic language such as "does hereby remise, release and quit-claim unto said" and instead encourages the use of plain language which a layperson at least has a reasonable chance of following. Someone with legal experience can easily understand what this document is, but I doubt many laypersons would agree that it is straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The document involves the bank cancelling the deed of trust (i.e. basically the mortgage) that you gave to the bank for the loan, because it was paid in full.

In a deed of trust, the legal fiction is that you transfer the property to a trustee for the benefit of the bank. The bank was a grantee of an equitable interest in the property and a beneficiary of the trustee of the deed of trust.

You were the grantor in the original transaction, giving the property to the trustee of the deed of trust, in which the bank and the trustee were grantees.

Now, the bank is the grantor giving back to you what you gave up when the deed of trust was created, and you are the grantee of the rights that the bank acquired under the deed of trust.

This is a routine document with nothing that seems to be amiss or needs to be clarified. It just means that the deed of trust is gone and that the property is now free and clear again. Depending upon local real estate practice, it may need to be recorded to establish that fact in the public record.

Comment: This helps me understand better. I think the key part to my misunderstanding was the multiple uses of the word "grantor". Since I was the original grantor, and the bank is the current grantor, that makes more sense. Thank you

Comment: I understand the structure of the transaction, but I'm also confused by the use of the word "Grantor" - it seems the Grantor defined in the first paragraph (the bank) is not the same Grantor to which rights are being released in the second paragraph (the OP)? I don't understand why the same term is used to refer to two different parties.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie The borrower was the original grantor in the deed of trust transaction giving the bank a lien on his property. The bank is the grantor in the current transaction giving the lien interest back to the borrower.